# A relation between the inner and outer jordan measures

Tags: measure-theory

I'm studying measure theory and I was thinking about the following question:

Is it true that whenever $A\subset B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are bounded,

$$m^*(B-A)=m^*(B)-m_*(A)?$$

I have easily established the inequality $m^*(B-A)\le m^*(B)-m_*(A)$. I can prove the reverse inequality when $B$ is Jordan measurable. My guess is that the reverse inequality does not necessarily hold, but I could not find any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

:-) Suppose that $B$ is not Jordan measurable and $A=B$. Then 
$$m^*(B-A)=m^*(B-B)=m^*(\varnothing)=0<m^*(B)-m_*(B)=m^*(B)-m_*(A).$$

Comment: Indeed, so nice and simple. Thanks! :)